# Can't understand css flexbox in this situation

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm studying css flexbox.

I found [this](https://codepen.io/YOONBYEONGIN/pen/pKKqag?editors=1100) example of usage of flexbox.

If I delete `.cards__item { display: flex; }`(line:32). the height of card is shrink!.

And I can't understand why `.cards__item { display: flex; }` make height of all `.cards__item` same.

Is this just a rule to remember ?

Comment: the answer is a bit long but take the time to read it and follow the links. You will understand more than you want ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you :D